# Set Excel 2010 file format in the registry

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, windows-registry, microsoft-office

If you install MS Office (2010 in my case) and run up any of the programs (Excel in my case) for the first time you encounter the following dialogs:

The Username dialog for setting a default user name and initial for the user (I have already set them ahead in the registry)

Then the registration dialog - I have already registered it and have activated it through command line and last but not least another dialog trying to determine what file formats to use by default.

How do I go about setting this in the registry so it doesn't come up when I run excel for the first time?

Comment: i dont have an account on that site, can this question be moved there ? @IvayloSlavov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was resolved by setting a default format from my template.
so i dint have to do it on individual VMs